# How can i upload a video to Facebook via PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, video, upload

i read some documents but its not clearly described any where. could you tell me step by step, how can i upload a video to facebook via php?

```
-register facebook
-verify account
-create facebook app
then???
```

Comment: Facebook provides pretty complete documentation for everything thier API offers.. check here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ Then if you still can't get it working, post here with what you've got, and see if someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this how-to: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload

Comment: And here is the documentation (which links to the how-tos):https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/